# Does Fancybox 2 work with earlier versions of jquery?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I see in the instructions to install Fancybox 2 a reference to jQuery 1.7. Does anybody know if earlier versions of jQuery can be used instead, specifically v1.3.2?

I use the latest version of jQuery on other sites. However, I have one site that is using an old CMS with that old version of jQuery; and of course it's not easy to replace the version.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it would be nice to know if it will work or not before trying it

Answer (score 2):

fancyBox2 uses "delegate" (since jQuery 1.4.2) and this bug - http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6913 - breaks slideshow if using jQuery prior 1.6.

You are always recommended to use the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: does not run on 1.4.2 for me